# Why django uses a comma as decimal separator

Tags: python, django, decimal

I am using python 2.6 and django 1.27

my model

```
class Plan(models.Model):
     price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2,default=0)
     .....
```

in my template i have

```
{{plan.price}}
```

My problem is that on my local machine i get dot used as separator for example '2.54'
While on my production machine i get '2,54' - comma is used as separator.
I would like it to use dot everywhere.

in the django docs 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/settings/#decimal-separator
it say there is the "DECIMAL_SEPARATOR" option the default it dot.

btw in both machines

```
In [2]: from django.conf import settings
In [3]: print settings.DECIMAL_SEPARATOR
.
```

**SOLUTION:**

as @Marcin pointed out
setting USE_L10N to False on production machine.

Comment: Does your server [Swiss(German)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/formatting/#switzerland-german)?

Comment: i would think my server has no nationality ;), how do i check it ?\

Comment: Check [those settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#globalization-i18n-l10n) in your django settings file.

Comment: i dont have any language settings.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, I assume you have L10N and I18N turned on in your `settings.py`, because that's the default. The difference you see is likely because you are accessing the website from two different computers with two different locales. Django tries to format things for the locale reported by the browser.

However, you can disable this behaviour. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/. Set `USE_L10N=False`, and set the various separator options specified on the linked page.

Comment: i accessed them both from the same computer, i will try setting the USE_L10 to false.

Comment: yeah it did the job. although i dont understand because it was the same computer and browser..

Comment: @yossi Possibly your dev installation is broken such that it couldn't use the L10N information (e.g. no locale information installed).

Answer (score 30):

You can use this alternative way directly on your template:

```
{% load l10n %}

{% localize off %}
{{ my_floatvar }}
{% endlocalize %}
```

or this one:

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ my_floatvar|unlocalize }}
```

More info in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#controlling-localization-in-templates

Comment: I know this is kinda old but I want to ask what could I be doing wrong if it's not working on my case? If I set the platform lang=ES (Spanish) it uses coma, but if I set lang=EN (English) it uses a dot. I tried the two methods you posted and even with localize off or on it just do not work.