# Django wrongly converting float x.xx to x,xx in template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a problem with my Django website. I'm passing a variable `latitude_actuelle` corresponding to a latitude from a view to a template. When I print the variable in the view, it's a float in a correct format `x.xx`. But when I display the variable in the template with {{ latitude_actuelle }}, the dot has been replaced by a comma : `x,xx` which is not a correct format for a float. The problem is that I need the float to be in a correct format in order to center a google map at the given latitude and longitude using javascript in the template.

I thought about modifying the variable in the script with something like this :

```
var lat_actuelle = {{ latitude_actuelle }}
use float(lat_actuelle.replace(',','.'))
```

But it looks like we cannot access template variables this way in javascript.

Is there a way to disable the wrong conversion of the float from `x.xx` to `x,xx` ? And if not, how can I solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance !

Here are the relevant part of my file if needed :

view

```
def infos_localisation(request):
    latitude_actuelle = 50.66981991272638
    longitude_actuelle = 4.615554319641566
    point = request.user.useradvanced.localisation
    if point != None:
        latitude_actuelle = float(point.y)
        longitude_actuelle = float(point.x)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LocationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            longitude = float(form.cleaned_data['longitude'].replace(',','.'))
            latitude = float(form.cleaned_data['latitude'].replace(',','.'))
            request.user.useradvanced.localisation = Point(longitude, latitude)
            request.user.useradvanced.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Votre localisation a été correctement mise à jour')
            return redirect("informations")
    else:
        form = LocationForm()

    return render(request, 'inscription/infos_localisation.html', locals())
```

javascript

```
function initMap() {
  act = {lat: "{{ latitude_actuelle }}", lng: "{{ longitude_actuelle }}"}
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: act, zoom: 15});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: act, map: map});
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = "{{ longitude_actuelle }}";
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = "{{ latitude_actuelle }}";
}
```

Comment: *"But when I display the variable in the template with {{ latitude_actuelle }}, the dot has been replaced by a comma : x,xx which is not a correct format for a float."* It is in many locales. It sounds like Django is using the wrong locale. So that's where I'd look to fix it. (I don't know Django, so can't point to the config that would address locale...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not really understanding what your point is. What do you mean by "locale" ?

Comment: A "locale" is a set of rules, etc., that defines how numbers, dates, and other things are displayed depending on language/culture/location - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software) In many places/languages/cultures, `,` is a decimal separator.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566673/why-django-uses-a-comma-as-decimal-separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566673/why-django-uses-a-comma-as-decimal-separator) proposed in the comments, I've found the solution. Here it is :

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ latitude_actuelle|unlocalize }}
```